# Error Installing Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2010 in my laptop ( OS: Windows 8.1 64bit )

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2010

I have tried many times to install Visual Studio Professional 2010 in my laptop many times but failed.

I got a ISO image from `dreamspark` and unzip using `7-zip` then from the download folder I clicked the `setup.exe` . It will start download but always pop up an error message :

```
DDSet_Error: Internal error:1009.
```

( screenshot link :  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5C33F7D4E7D75338%21845 )

As per requested by Ramhound:
here are the error logs link below

vslogs.cab:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5C33F7D4E7D75338%21848

Anybody who could find the problem pls let me know thanks

Comment: Post the more detailed information from the log file that will help determine what is causing this specific error.

Comment: Please don't corss-post between SE sites (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906662/error-installing-microsoft-visual-studio-professional-2010-in-my-laptop-os-wi) pick one and post it there. If you'd like it moved, flag a mod and request it be migrated.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It's more suitable here though. Maybe it should be removed from SO

Comment: Does your ISO have VS2010's Service Pack 1 or higher included with it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows 8, try mounting the image instead of unzipping it. Windows 8 has a built in mount function (if you cannot find it try open with windows explorer). That's how I installed it. Sometimes when unzipping ISO images something goes wrong with the files.